# How to change paragraph whenever a particular option is selected from dropdown menu?

Tags: angular, angular8

Vague title but I want to change the waiting_time variable whenever Dr.name is selected from dropdown menu, but since Dr is outside the scope I cannot do it.

```html
<div class="container well">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedDr" name="selectedDr">
            <option *ngFor="let Dr of configDr">{{ Dr.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <p>Estimated waiting time is: {{ waiting_time }} minutes</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
showConfig() {
    this.EmployeeData.getConfig()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.configDr = data as Config [];
      });
  }
```

Comment: you could bind the `<select>` to `(change)` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `change` event for this purpose:

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="modelChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedDr" name="selectedDr">
     <option *ngFor="let Dr of configDr" value="{{Dr.name}}">{{ Dr.name }}</option>
</select>
```

and in your component.ts file:

```
public modelChanged(event){
   let value = event.source.value; //this line is used incase you are not using ngModel
   this.waiting_time='your desired value';
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `event.source.value` when you could use `selectedDr` since it is bound to the `select` ?

Comment: @callback yes ofcourse, no need for it, but i just added it for example, if anyone is not using ngModel

Comment: Fair enough.. :)